# Android. Force ANR dump

Tags: android, adb

Is there any way to request dump for an arbitrary process, that will be similar to one generated for ANR's at `/data/anr/traces.txt`? Probably it should be possible via device's shell.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

After some research efforts I've figured out that it is possible, but unfortunately not very useful. So, to add dump of your process to `/data/anr/traces.txt` you should just send `SIGQUIT` to process you are interested in. You can simply run next from device shell:

```
$ kill -s SIGQUIT <pid>
```

And the only problem is that not every user can send signals to arbitrary processes. It shouldn't be an issue on rooted devices. For the rest ones you still can use this trick if package of your app is debuggable. This fact allows to use `run-as` utility and execute `kill` as user of investigated process:

```
$ adb shell
shell@mako:/ $ run-as com.example.sysuser.stunprober                           
shell@mako:/data/data/com.example.sysuser.stunprober $ kill -s SIGQUIT 4712
```

And logcat output shows that dump was written:

```
I/art(4712): Thread[5,tid=4721,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb74c4d28,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art(4712): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Note, you may need to create the /data/anr directory first.

# logcat -d | tail
E/dalvikvm(  620): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': No such file or directory
# mkdir /data/anr
# kill -s SIGQUIT 620                                          
 # logcat -d | tail                                              
I/dalvikvm(  620): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'